# Python pattern-matching. Match 'c[any number of consecutive a's, b's, or c's or b's, c's, or a's etc.]t'

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

Sorry about the title, I couldn't come up with a clean way to ask my question.

In Python I would like to match an expression 'c[some stuff]t', where [some stuff] could be any number of consecutive a's, b's, or c's and in any order.

For example, these work:
**'ct'**, **'cat'**, **'cbbt'**, **'caaabbct'**, **'cbbccaat'**

but these don't:
**'cbcbbaat'**, **'caaccbabbt'**

Edit: a's, b's, and c's are just an example but I would really like to be able to extend this to more letters. I'm interested in regex and non-regex solutions.

Comment: It seems from the majority of responses that the only way to encode this is manually setting up all of the cases. Is this true? This would be very hard if I wanted to add two more letters. I think that would be 120 cases.

Comment: @Wooble - No, I just want the solution to be extensible. The completely manual/direct approach would require a lot of typing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure how attached you are to regex, but here is a solution using a different method:

```
from itertools import groupby

words = ['ct', 'cat', 'cbbt', 'caaabbct', 'cbbccaat',  'cbcbbaat', 'caaccbabbt']
for w in words:
    match = False
    if w.startswith('c') and w.endswith('t'):
        temp = w[1:-1]
        s = set(temp)
        match = s <= set('abc') and len(s) == len(list(groupby(temp)))
    print w, "matches" if match else "doesn't match"
```

The string matches if a set of the middle characters is a subset of `set('abc')` and the number of groups returned by `groupby()` is the same as the number of elements in the set.

Comment: I'm interested in how the efficiencies compare. I'm not necessarily attached to regex.

Comment: Very nice, and also easily extensible! I wrote a non-regexp answer myself, but yours is much better, so I'm just giving you an upvote instead of posting mine.

Comment: @Andrew - I like how this is very human readable. This solution also appeals to my mathematical side with the inclusion of sets. Seems efficient, how does it compare to regex? Anyone?

Comment: @Usagi: it should be linear in the length of the string, so asymptotically, you can't beat it.

Answer (score 14):

Not thoroughly tested, but I think this should work:

```
import re

words = ['ct', 'cat', 'cbbt', 'caaabbct', 'cbbccaat',  'cbcbbaat', 'caaccbabbt']
pat = re.compile(r'^c(?:([abc])\1*(?!.*\1))*t$')
for w in words:
    print w, "matches" if pat.match(w) else "doesn't match"

#ct matches
#cat matches
#cbbt matches
#caaabbct matches
#cbbccaat matches
#cbcbbaat doesn't match
#caaccbabbt doesn't match
```

This matches runs of `a`, `b` or `c` (that's the `([abc])\1*` part), while the negative lookahead `(?!.*\1)` makes sure no other instance of that character is present after the run.

(edit: fixed a typo in the explanation)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to explicitly encode all possible permutations of `a`s, `b`s and `c`s:

```
c(a*b*c*|b*a*c*|b*c*a*|c*b*a*|c*a*b*|a*c*b*)t
```

Note that this is an extremely inefficient query which may backtrack a lot.

Comment: It does? Seems to me that at most the whole string could be analized 6 times before failing. I don't see any exponential explosion typical of problematic regexps...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Python regex engine, but it sounds like you just want to write out the 6 different possible orderings directly.

```
/c(a*b*c*|a*c*b*|b*a*c*|b*c*a*|c*a*b*|c*b*a*)t/
```

Comment: Is there another way? If I wanted to add d and e, for instance, I would have to manually type 120 cases.

Comment: @Usagi No. Anything more complicated and you really should ditch regular expressions and parse it manually instead.

Comment: @Usagi: You can write a function that generates the regex string fairly easily to avoid the manual typing.

Comment: @trutheality: Sure, but you're getting into extreme inefficiencies with all the backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no "compact" way of doing this...

```
c(a*(b*c*|c*b*)|b*(a*c*|c*a*)|c*(a*b*|b*a*))t
```